# I don't know how to export a private key from blockchain.info

Tags: private-key

I am trying to make a raw transaction which requires a private key but i can't seem to find a way to get it from blockchain.info.

Answer (score 3):

The exact steps can be found quite easily via Google. [This GitHub page](https://github.com/OmniLayer/omniwallet/wiki/Exporting-Private-Key-from-Blockchain.info-and-Importing-to-Omniwallet.org#for-blockchaininfo-addresses-imported-into-the-new-blockchaininfo-wallet-from-blockchaininfos-classic-wallets) was the first result when I searched for it. Quote:

> 1. Login to your wallet on Blockchain.info
> 2. Goto the 'Settings' Menu on the left
> 3. Goto the 'Addresses' Submenu under 'Settings' Menu
> 4. On the right side find the section named 'Imported Addresses'
> 5. Click on 'Manage Addresses'
> 6. On the new screen find the address you want to export the private key from
> 7. Click on the 'More Options' on far right side of that address
> 8. Select 'Private Key' and then 'Continue'

Comment: That will only work for imported addresses, not for the wallet itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple tutorial on how to export the private keys on your blockchain account https://bl4nkcode.info/bitcoin/how_to_export_blockchain_wallet_private_key since blockchain wallet follow the format of BIP39

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:

1. Go to settings, then click addresses as shown below:

[image]

2. Click on more options aside your address whose private key you require as shown below:

[image]

3. In 'More Options' you will find "Private Key", please click it:

[image]

4. They will show you a warning as below, please click continue:

[image]

5. You can see your private key for the corresponding wallet address:

[image]

Hope this helps you!

Comment: can you provide qr-code in better format? it is too hard to decode it https://imgur.com/WIOgxh0  :)

Comment: Good luck with that mate :D Though it has got nothing :D

Comment: it is not nothing. it is challenge. and a joke of course :)