# How to find the private key of blockchain wallet?

Tags: address, private-key, private-key-export

How to find the private key of blockchain wallet of this address 1DkyBEKt5S2GDtv7aQw6rQepAvnsRyHoYM

Comment: Without more information (did you ever have it, what wallet/service did you use, ...), the answer is "you don't".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I don't know how to export a private key from blockchain.info](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50747/i-dont-know-how-to-export-a-private-key-from-blockchain-info)

Answer (score 3):

I am hoping you are talking about blockchain.info

If yes, then I am again hoping that the above address you have posted is a wallet address in your blockchain.info

If again, the answer is yes, please follow the below steps:

1. Go to settings, then click addresses as shown below:

[image]

2. Click on more options aside your address whose private key you require as shown below:

[image]

3. In 'More Options' you will find "Private Key", please click it:

[image]

4. They will show you a warning as below, please click continue:

[image]

5. You can see your private key for the corresponding wallet address:

[image]

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Be aware that I was able to partially recover the private key from the QR code in your screenshot, so you probably want to edit that out (and contact Stack Exchange to have the original version purged).

Comment: I know people will do that mate, it's an empty wallet, and I don't use that ;)