# How do i find my private keys in my blockchain.info wallet?

Tags: blockchain.info, private-key

I've tried numerous times to find private key in settings/addresses, but can't find any.

My question is not like the other problems here, because i cannot even see my private key. I can find xPub extended private key on my default wallet. But is that the same thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I don't know how to export a private key from blockchain.info](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50747/i-dont-know-how-to-export-a-private-key-from-blockchain-info)

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the below steps:

1. Go to settings, then click addresses as shown below:

[image]

2. Click on more options aside your address whose private key you require as shown below:

[image]

3. In 'More Options' you will find "Private Key", please click it:

[image]

4. They will show you a warning as below, please click continue:

[image]

5. You can see your private key for the corresponding wallet address:

[image]

Hope this helps you!

Comment: On my addresses page there is none of your screen shots there.

Comment: Are you using a desktop/laptop to access or a mobile? The above are screenshots from the former one.

Comment: desktop application

Comment: Please go to blockchain.info there is no desktop application of blockchain.info.

Comment: sorry i meant the web browser on my desktop pc, not desktop application.  How do i add images to these comments?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/GFHZfUu.png

Comment: The image in the link above has been edited to remove any identifying information

Comment: You have no addresses, then how can you get the private key mate. Click "+ ADD" to create a new wallet, then you can access it. Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/h5u079

Comment: But i've been purchasing bitcoin through the wallet, and I have a bitcoin total, and association value. Why do i need to create a new address?

Comment: I've done just as you ask and now that address has no bitcoins in it?

Comment: So what do i do now? https://i.imgur.com/nFGYTcn.png

Comment: If you were buying BTC, were you sending those BTC to this wallet in Blockchain.info?

Comment: I was buying BTC through the wallet. Have BTC in the wallet. your images have no corresponding view on my wallet. I can see on other answers, that yoiu've used the same images, I wonder if these are taken from an earlier version of the site. I can find 'xPub' but no where does it give you the link for private keys. I have used addresses, that show a new address for each purchase, but no links to private keys for these either.

Comment: i could not find the way to get private keys on bc.i by this manual. May be it depends on security settings (2fa, email confirmation, etc)

Comment: This tutorial was made just few days back for another question. It is working for me with security settings of 2FA and Email Confirmation. I don't know why this is not working for the OP. Hope some other answer will surely help you mate.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s how to export your private keys on blockchain.info:
https://medium.com/@bL4nkcode/how-to-export-blockchain-infos-private-key-2ac84057d2d1