# How to move blockchain.info api created wallet to be used by bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain.info

I originally created my wallet through the blockchain.info api.  I have since downloaded the bitcoin core and it's finishing downloading all the blocks now.  What is the process to access this wallet directly?  Also, is this a one way transfer, or will it still be usable through the blockchain.info api?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to extract the private key from blockchain.info, and get it imported into bitcoin core. See here:

[I don't know how to export a private key from blockchain.info](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50747/i-dont-know-how-to-export-a-private-key-from-blockchain-info)

You may need to repeat this step, if you have several wallets in blockchain.info.
Once done, it is like having two wallets, with the same privkey. Nothing prevents you from using both.