# How to find private key in blockchain.info account?

Tags: blockchain.info

I have been trying to send some bitcoin from my blockchain.info account but was asked to provide my private key how can I find my private key on blockchain wallet?

Comment: Maybe a similar question, and some answers here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/68196/how-to-move-blockchain-info-api-created-wallet-to-be-used-by-bitcoin-core

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to export your private keys directly unless its an imported address that you imported to your wallet.

**To get the private keys for your main wallet addresses:**

1. login to blockchain.info.
2. Click Settings > Security > Backup Recovery Phrase > write down your phrase with exact order to import it later using Electrum wallet.
3. Download [**Electrum bitcoin wallet**](https://electrum.org/) and setup on your computer.
4. Start Electrum then choose file > new/restore > click next > choose the option "Standard Wallet" > then choose I already have a seed.
5. Enter the seed phrase you saved from Blockchain.info then click next you can choose a password to protect your wallet.
6. Now you control your wallet  click addresses tab then choose the address you want right click and choose **private key** option.

[image]

***Dont give your private keys to anyone not to lose your coins***